# systemd does not notice apache starts

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, systemd, debian-jessie

My debian-system has been infected with the systemd-virus...

When I issue the "service apache2 start" command to start apache, it thinks it failed, but apache is running just fine.
So "service apache2 stop" does nothing, because system thinks apache has not started. To stop apache, I have to issue "killall apache2"

```
# service apache2 start
Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' 
   and 'journalctl -xn' for details.


# systemctl status apache2.service 
â apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-06-09 15:49:43 CEST; 32s ago
  Process: 7513 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 09 15:49:43  apache2[7513]: Starting web server: apache2 failed!
Jun 09 15:49:43  apache2[7513]: The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems ... (warning).
Jun 09 15:49:43  systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 09 15:49:43  systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jun 09 15:49:43  systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
```

The system is debian 8.5; upgraded through many versions.

Why does "system" think it failed, when apache is started just fine?

```
[Thu Jun 09 16:11:40.945575 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 13426] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jun 09 16:11:40.945846 2016] [core:notice] [pid 13426] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

**UPDATE**
The /etc/init.d/apache2 looks for a pidfile at

```
/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
```

, but the file actually is at

```
/var/run/apache2.pid
```

, i.e. a subdir less.

Comment: Can you provide the Apache error log as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pidfile was in an unexpected place.
Editing

```
/etc/apache2/envvars
```

the line

```
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX.pid
```

made the "service apache2 start/stop" work